# Typescript error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying compile this typescript file:

```
import http = module("http");
import express = module("express");
```

With these parameters:

```
C:/nodejs/tsc.cmd --sourcemap cheese.ts --module commonjs
C:/User/Node/ExpressProject/cheese.ts(5,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
C:/User/Node/ExpressProject/cheese.ts(6,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

What am I doing wrong? Even with this, I am getting the same errors errors:

```
module "http" {}
module "express" {}

import http = module("http");
import express = module("express");
```

Using Typescript version 0.9.1

Comment: @Connor: Were you able to reproduce the error? And yes, I name all my foo files cheese. Its a habbit, really! :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax in `0.9.1` is now `import mod = require('modname');`

Comment: Let's hear it for more of those famous TypeScript helpful errors!

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compiler (https://www.npmjs.org/package/typescript-compiler) commands.

I use --allowimportmodule

Answer (score 1):

I was getting these errors with a .Net Core application in Visual Studio  Professional 2019, I got the 16.4.4 update and applied that which in turn had a requirement to reboot the computer which of course closed and then re-opened the solution.  After this, the various TS errors went away.