# Multiple Typescript errors after upgrading from Angular 2.3.0 to 4.X

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I upgraded from `Angular 2.3.0` to `Angular 4.3.0` and it broke my app. Here are the errors I'm getting. I'm getting several hundred `TS1110` and `TS1005`. I get errors from all angular modules - `core`, `compiler`, `router` etc.

```
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(44,35): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(44,82): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(78,18): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(79,35): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(80,30): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(80,79): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(82,55): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(83,42): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(83,79): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(84,99): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(85,65): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(86,53): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(86,90): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(87,64): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(87,101): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(88,60): error TS1110: Type expected.
    node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(89,63): error TS1110: Type expected.
   node_modules/@angular/core/src/view/types.d.ts(431,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
   node_modules/@angular/core/src/view/types.d.ts(431,23): error TS1005: ';' expected.
   node_modules/@angular/core/src/view/types.d.ts(432,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
   node_modules/@angular/core/src/view/types.d.ts(432,23): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I've referred to the following resources without any luck.

1. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/171
2. [Typescript error TS1005: ';' expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293590/typescript-error-ts1005-expected)

I even upgraded `typescript` to `2.4.2` and tried variety of permutation and combination.

Here's my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.2.0",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/ora": "^0.3.31",
    "@types/rimraf": "^0.0.28",
    "amqplib": "^0.5.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.10",
    "compression": "^1.5.2",
    "connect": "^3.4.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "date-and-time": "^0.4.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-cache-response-directive": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "groc": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
    "highcharts-ng": "0.0.11",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongojs": "^2.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.7.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.2.0",
    "path": "~0.12.7",
    "q": "~1.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.0",
    "simple-text-parser": "~0.1.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you delete your node_modules folder then reinstall them?

Comment: Yes.I did that.